# Alert input "file" filename using jQuery with "split"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to alert the filename from a upload input.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwdct/)

It works, but there's the "C:Fakepath..." something like that.
I just want the filename, without the Fake path. I tried using the `split` function, but I'm not sure why it's not working.

Example html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="file" id="tester" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Example script:

```
$(function() {
    var bogus;
    var triple;
    $('#tester').change(function() {

        triple = $('#tester').val();
        bogus = triple.split(/[\s/]+/);

        alert(bogus[bogus.length - 1]);
    });
});
```

​
Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just `$('#tester').val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\", "")`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just escape the slash:

```
   bogus = triple.split("\\");
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/xwdct/3/

Comment: Perfect. So simple! Thank you. (can't give you the "Answer"  check until 11 minutes

Answer (score 0):

If your web browser supports the [File API](http://caniuse.com/#search=File%20API) (currently, this is any web browser that isn't IE), you can get the file name from the input's FileList object.

```
$(function() {
    $('#tester').change(function() {
        var files = this.files;
        if (files && files.length) {
            alert(files[0].name); //use the file api
        }
        else {
            alert($(this).val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\", ""));  //this is for IE
        }
    });
});​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NTICompass/xwdct/6/

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications